# Derivation of heat equation on a circle

Tags: fourier-analysis, heat-equation

For the temperature distribution $u(x,y,t)$. I know the heat equation on a plane is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=c(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2})$. But if we consider the heat equation on a circle, we can express $u(x,y,t)=u(cos2\pi s,sin2\pi s,t)$ where $s\in [0,1]$. I am trying to derive the equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=c'(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s^2})$ given in Fourier analysis by Stein.

I computed $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s^2}=4\pi ^2(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2})-4\pi ^2cos(2\pi s)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-4\pi^2sin(2\pi s)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. And I am stuck here. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the first volume of Stein & Shakarchi? If so, which page?

Comment: @HansLundmark yes. Page 119

Comment: @HansLundmark I hope I did not misunderstand his equation,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle here is modelled exactly as a rod, i.e., with the one-dimensional heat equation $u_t = c u_{xx}$, the only difference being that the solution is required to be periodic in $x$. (Imagine the rod being bent around, and the ends joined, to make a ring.)

It has nothing to do with the heat equation for a disk.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should not apply the heat equation on the plane to a circle as for a circle $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ are not even defined.